# C# combobox selection feeding another combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

using mysql I feed combobox2 with selection of combobox1.It works OK. but the problem is the first select seems does not trigger the eventhandler. the second time I do it it will trigger.

`private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_selectedvaluechanged);
                       }`

`private void comboBox1_selectedvaluechanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            region = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            values_to_venue();
            db.connection.Close();
        }`

Comment: I think the event you want to use is ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted because if the user navigates the DropDown list using the up/down arrows on the keypad, SelectedIndexChanged will fire before the selection is committed - is that what you want??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not creating your event handler until the SelectedIndex of the combobox changes.  This is fired alongside SelectedValue changes.  Create the event handler in the load method ensuring it is there when the first SelectedValue changes.  If you put it in the Load make sure you clean it up with -= in the unload.  Or, you can just create it in the constructor and then you won't need to remove it.

Comment: you're right. If he does not know very well what he must do: put this line : comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_selectedvaluechanged); in the function where you load the form

Comment: I move the code from private void comboBox1_selectedIndexChanged to the initializeComponent and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to set the events in your constructor or load method; also, I think the event you want to use is ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted because if the user navigates the DropDown list using the up/down arrows on the keypad, SelectedIndexChanged will fire before the selection is committed - is that what you want??????